# Error trying to open/test/run React Native APK in Android Studio

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, apk

My friend made me an APK file using react native. When I try to test and publish it through Android Studio I keep getting two errors.

When I first try to run it I see "Error: Please select Android SDK" on the edit configuration screen. I've updated/installed SDK's twice now. No change.

If I still click RUN and continue anyways, it doesn't work and I get the error "No JDK specified for module [apk name]

Please help!